# Incredibuild build issue with newer version 10.1.10

Tags: incredibuild

we have upgrade our incredibuild to the newer version 10.1.10.
Now we are facing one issue with BuildConsole.exe.
First we are building one clean build of project.
After that when we are building some other project its start building once again already build dependency project, which unnessasery taking a lot of time for build the project.
we are using below command:

"..\BuildConsole.exe" build\example.sln /build /CFG="RelWithDebInfo|x64" /PRJ="test" /CL_REM="/Zi /ZI" /NoLogo /ShowTime /All

We tried to use /pemode=0 in command line but we are facing same issue.